# How to rotate a UIbutton in Xcode + IB?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface, interface-builder

I am writing an iPhone programer, and 
I want to make a button with is rotate 180 degree, I try to use the multi-touch track pad to rotate a UIbutton, but it don't success, how can I do it? or I need to do it by code?

Comment: May I ask - why do you want to do this? Rotating a button independantly of the rest of the display is rarely a good thing to do. Just curious.

Comment: Can I ask why it is a bad idea?

Comment: It's not part of the normal User Experience. Can look jarring. If there is a specific and reasonable purpose for it it may be ok - but they are very rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here we go:

```
CABasicAnimation *halfTurn;
halfTurn = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
halfTurn.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
halfTurn.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
halfTurn.duration = 0.5;
halfTurn.repeatCount = 1;
[myButton addAnimation:halfTurn forKey:@"180"];
```

Hope that helps... Im typing from my PC though, not my Mac - So I hope that's right!

Comment: Wow... Keep it simple!
Why using an animation to rotate a single element, since you can do it using a single property of the object? IMHO, it's useless, it made to code uselessly complex, and it not good at all for performance...

Comment: This code functions, and is a *nice* standard way to rotate an object - just ENSURE that you RELEASE it all afterwards.

Comment: It did not say your code does not work. I'm just saying this can be done in another way, which is easier and more performant.

Comment: I think there was just a fundamental ambiguity in the original question. Does "rotate" mean "transform to a rotated position", or does it make "make it rotate" as in an animation. I took it the first way, as Macmade evidentally did. It looks like you took it the second way - which is equally valid, but leads to a different answer.

Comment: I believe you can autorelease "halfturn"; addAnimation should keep it retained. Didn't test though.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `myButton.layer`?

Answer (score 22):

You can't do it from Interface Builder. You have to rotate it from your code, using the transform property of your UIButton, which is a CGAffineTransform struct.
You can use the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation() to set it.

```
myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ( 180 * M_PI ) / 180 );
```

The first 180 in the code is the angle in degrees. The operation converts it to radians.

Answer (score 5):

I was wanting to do this same thing - rotate a button 180 degrees when tapped - but do it using an animation. [Neurofluxation's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455334/how-to-rotate-a-uibutton-in-xcode-ib/2455400#2455400) does the 180 degree rotation with an animation, but it isn't permanent. [Macmade's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455334/how-to-rotate-a-uibutton-in-xcode-ib/2455377#2455377) does the 180 degree rotation, but doesn't do it with an animation. So if you're like me and would like to do a 180 degree rotation with animation use this code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35];

// (180 * M_PI) / 180 == M_PI, so just use M_PI
myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

As well, if you want to rotate back to the starting position (ie 0 degree rotation) then put the following in between the animation code like above:

```
myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
```

As to a use case for such a button, Evernote's show/hide keyboard button does a really slick 180 degree rotation which can be [recreated](http://www.yycapps.com/2011/07/creating-a-keyboard-show-hide-button/) using the above code.